# Use one UICollectionViewCell prototype for different situations

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I try to create chat view with message bubbles using UICollectionView. 
I want to show message with attachments in one bubble, not in differnt bubbles.
Maximum count of attachment is 10.

```
|----------------------------| 
|       |------------|       |
|       |  Text      |       |
|       |------------|       |
|                            |
|       |------------|       |
|       |attacment 1 |       |
|       |------------|       |
|                            |
|       |------------|       |
|       |attacment 2 |       |
|       |------------|       |
|                            |
|       |------------|       |
|       |attacment 3 |       |
|       |------------|       |
|                            /  
|--------------------------\ \
                            \__>
```

**My problem is:**
I don't want to create 10 prototype cells for each situation ( text + 1 attachment, text + 2 attachment, ..., text + 10 attachment).

**My question is:**
Can I create one subclass and prototype of UICollectionViewCell with all ui elements and constraints, then remove unneccesary ones in the code
and use different reuseIdentifiers for each situation? ( text + 1 attachment, text + 2 attachment, ..., text + 10 attachment).
Or may be I can solve my problem another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be the best. For instance, you could put a dynamic table view inside the collection view cell which enables you to add as many attachments as you want.

Comment: Use a view for the header marked "Text" on your graph. Doing this will allow you create a pure dynamic table view, so avoid using "Text" as first row.

Comment: Thank you for help! I have tried to use your approach, but I have some misunderstanding: When I configure attachment tableviews in -tableview: cellForRowAtIndexPath: how can I know which message tableview I’m going to configure? (in another words: for which bubble this tableview is belongs to)

Comment: I think it worths to open a new question.